# Numpy Vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have a vector A of shape (10,); vector B of shape (20,) ; matrix C of shape (10,20). I want to compute a matrix D of shape (10,20) such that:

```
A = np.ones((10))
B = np.ones((20))
C = np.ones((10,20))
D = (np.log(B/A) + C**2*B)/(C*np.sqrt(B))
```

How would I vectorize such an equation?

Comment: You would have to use broadcasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
import numpy as np


A = np.ones((10, 1))
B = np.ones((1, 20))
C = np.ones((10,20))
D = (np.log(B/A) + C**2*B)/(C*np.sqrt(B))
```